# FiveTen Freeriders vs Freeriders VXi

Tags: mountain-bike, shoes

I can't decide between these two models. I need them mostly for technical trail riding, like getting on boulders on the way up (I'm fine with cleats going down, but on the way up on each mistake I have to find my way to unclip to put a feet, and 50% of the time I don't quite succeed in that and lay sideways). Does the new VXi bald sole design sacrifices some of the grip in exchange for the ability to reposition the foot? What would be your choice?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the regular Freeride shoes and love how sticky they are. Haven't tried the new VXi ones, but I think the spot with no tread pattern would be a little nicer since you don't have to lift your foot to reposition. I'd recommend reading [Pinkbike's](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/Five-Ten-Freerider-VXi-Shoes-review-2013.html) review as they cover most of the relevant points.

Comment: I've got the regular Freerider too, but I'm intrigued by the VXi. The standard one gives you very little float and it can be tricky to re-position your foot on the pedal. That said, they do grip *very* well. I'm not sure if I want to trade one inconvenience for another. The factory jackson review might be useful, too: http://factoryjackson.com/2013/05/10/review-five-ten-freerider-vxi/